# How to display data from a parent site list on a subsite home page

Tags: web-part, sub-site, inheritance

This is best explained using an image:
[image: Inheriting data from parent site list]

I have a parent site with a list of products, each of which has its own Project sub-site. I want the home page of each sub-site to display data about its record from the list in the parent site. The text in the subsite can be plain text - it doesn't need to be edited or affect the original list in the parent site. The info should change if the record in the parent list is updated though.

Is there a way to do this without InfoPath? Is there a web part that will work?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this article [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this using JavaScript using REST API or JSOM. You can add a webpart that will query which site the webpart is on, then you can query that list in order to pull back the information for that list item.

EDIT: I may be a little bias in that approach

Comment: Hi Mike, Could you point me in some directions of how to achieve this approach? Do I have to create a custom webpart, or can I use JS Link to Lookup data and manipulate its output?

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by using OOB content Query web part.
Specify your list in Query property of webpart.
And select "Show items from the following list:" select your list Name.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this part now, thanks. I'll mark it as 'correct' if it works :)

Comment: No prob, i have tried this at my end and it works:)